# Usei setcookie no meu servidor local e deu tudo certo, mas quando subi para o servidor local não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Usei `setcookie("votados".$_POST['votacao'], 'yes', time()+86400*300);` no meu servidor local e funcionou divinamente bem, mas ao subir ele não funciona. Tipo, era pra ele checar se o usuário já votou ou não.
Alguém poderia me dar uma ajudinha?

Comment: se você quer permitir que as pessoas votem somente uma vez usar cookie pode não ser a melhor opção, visto que o usuario pode deleta-los facilmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se alguém, algum dia passar por um problema parecido com setcookie, aí vai a solução que encontrei:

```
ob_start ();  // No início do código 
ob_end_flush ();  // No final do código
```

Para saber mais a respeito do [ob_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) e [ob_end_flush](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php).